# Javascript for adding multiple array in html oninput

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

I have successfully pass parameter of skills in url from one page to another(job detail page to job listing page) by clicking  view more link but now in second page i need to show all those skills right after it open to the second page. [i have attached the image as u can see, once i type the skills, all skills appear there but in set of data and not showing only skill but i want skills with bullet point only to appear and once i click clear all it should remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Td0.png)So far, as i know it should use javascript and im not sure how to code it, can someone help me to solve this issue?

```js
function autoFilters()
 
    let availableSkills = [];
    @foreach($allSkill as $skill)
        availableSkills.push('{!! $skill !!}');
    @endforeach

    $("#skills").autocomplete({
        source: availableSkills
    });
    let addField = $('#skills');
    function onInput() 
    {
        let val = document.getElementById("skills").value;
        for (let i = 0; i < availableSkills.length; i++) 
        {
            if (availableSkills[i] === val) 
            {
                let skill = $('#skills').val();
                let fieldHTML = "<div class='border rounded mb-2 px-3 py-1 d-flex justify-content-between'><p class='m-0 skill-value'>"+skill+"</p><button type='button' class='btn rounded-0 float-right p-0 remove-skill'><i class='fas fa-times-circle crimson'></i></button></div>";
                $(fieldHTML).insertAfter(addField);
                $('#skills').val("");
                autoFilters();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
       
 
    $('.skill-wrapper').on('click','.remove-skill',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        autoFilters();
    });

    $('#clear-skills').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.skill-value').each(function(){
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
        });
        autoFilters();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="skill-wrapper">
  <input type="text" oninput='onInput()' id="skills" class="form-control height-43 full-width mb-2" placeholder="Enter Skills">
  <button type="submit" id="clear-skills" class="btn btn-primary btn-cerulean full-width mt-2">Clear all</button>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your onInput() function code? Pls add that to your question as well

Comment: yes @KiranDash i already add the code, can u assist me on how to get the skills javascript code?

Comment: @RubineRevichanran I changed your code into a snippet. Please complete the snippet so all the needed code to reproduce your problem is added.

Comment: @RubineRevichanran SO is a site to help people to fix/understand problems with their code. In order to do so you need to provide a minimal reproducible example of your issue. The snippet you posted now has syntax erros and contains javascript code that does nothing because the corresponding html elements are missing. If you want to work with Javascript but don't understand Javascript then I suggest to take a Javascript course first.

Comment: @MarkBaijens i have already remove the unwanted codes, and if i run in my laptop is fine but in snippet its keep showing error

Comment: @RubineRevichanran Replace the php/laravel code with some sample for availableSkills. These snippets run client side code only.

Answer (score -1):

```
function onChange() {
  let val = document.getElementById("skills").value;
  for (let i = 0; i < availableSkills.length; i++) {
    if (availableSkills[i] === val) {
      let skill = $('#skills').val();
      let fieldHTML = "<div class='border rounded mb-2 px-3 py-1 d-flex justify-content-between'><p class='m-0 skill-value'>" + skill + "</p><button type='button' class='btn rounded-0 float-right p-0 remove-skill'><i class='fas fa-times-circle crimson'></i></button></div>";
      $(fieldHTML).insertAfter(addField);
      $('#skills').val("");
      autoFilters();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Please Change onInput with onChange method.

Comment: i already try to change but still same, it shows the skills in set of data as in the link image i set above